# If $b$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0,1]$, then so is its power $b^k$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

If $b$ is a a continuous function on a close interval between $0$ and $1$, i.e. $b\in C([0,1])$.

Let $f(b)=b^k$, $k>1$, does $f(b)$ also lies in the same interval, i.e. $f(b)\in C([0,1])$?

My apology for this very silly question. I just need some assurance for an answer and appreciate any helps.

Comment: Yes, products of continuous functions are continuous. ($k \in \mathbb N$?)

Comment: If $b$ is a function, what exactly do you mean by $b^k$?  Do you mean iteration (e.g. $b^k(x) = b(b(\cdots b(x)\cdots ))$) or product (e.g. $b^k(x) = b(x)\cdot b(x)\cdots b(x)$)?

Comment: @anorton You are absolutely right.

Comment: @anorton I mean product.

Comment: Instead of saying how basic the question is, it is better to write a title that says what it actually is.

Comment: @Raffesia arnoldii   Thanks for the revised title

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity, assume $b$ is rational (this isn't necessary, but it makes an intuitive explanation easier). Now if $b$ is rational then we can write $b = \frac{m}{n}$ with $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. So then, if $b<1$, then $m<n$, so then 
$$f(b) = b^k = \left (\frac{m}{n} \right)^k = \frac{m^k}{n^k}$$
Since $m<n$, it must be the case that $m^k<n^k$, so then $0<\frac{m^k}{n^k}<1$.

Comment: $\;b\;$, in spite of its odd notation, is a function, *not* a number.